# Function in angular expression not updating when parameter has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```js
(function(){
  var app=angular.module('Tester',[]);
  
  app.controller('TestController',function($scope){
    $scope.days=[{name:'Sun'},{name:'Mon'},{name:'Teu'},{name:'Wed'},{name:'Thu'},{name:'Fri'},{name:'Sat'}];
    //if I is use `days=['Sun','Mon'...]` it works
    $scope.values={};
    $scope.add=function(values){
      var sum=0;
      $scope.days.map(function(v){
        v=values[v];
        if(v){
          sum+=(v-0);
        }
      });
      return sum;
    }
  });
  
  app.filter('sum',function(){
    return function(obj){
      var total=0;
      for(var v in obj){
        total+=(obj[v]-0)||0;
      }
      return total;
    }
  });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Tester">
  <div ng-controller="TestController as test">
    <input ng-model="values[day.name]" value="{{values[day.name]||0}}" ng-repeat="day in days">
    <div>{{add(values)}}</div>
    <div>{{values | sum}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to have a row of inputs and a total to show the sum. It works if I use `days=['Sun','Mon'...]` or a filter. But the filter seems semantically incorrect as well as not allowing me to add other properties to the values object (`value={'Mon':2,'time':123456789}` would give an incorrect sum) and `days=[{name:'Sun'}...]` allows me to store more information than `days=['Sun','Mon'...]` about each day.

Comment: why not to use the same implementation of the filter in `add` as well?

Comment: Because I need to store more information in the values object, which means the filter method will give incorrect results. eg `value={'Mon':2,'time':123456789}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your `add` function a bit, changing `v=values[v]` to `v=values[v.name]` inside the inner `map` function.

This is because your `days` array now contains objects (`{name: 'Mon'}` etc), so...

```
$scope.days.map(function (v) {
  // in here v = {name: 'Mon'}, not 'Mon' as previously, 
  // but the values object still has day names as keys:
  // {'Sun': 2, 'Mon': 1} etc.
  // --> values[v] === undefined, but values[v.name] matches
})
```

Below is the edit in place, and it works as I presume you wanted it to work. Oh, and I added the same `(v-0)||0` trick to the sum calculations, so that entering invalid data (text for example) doesn't break it up.

```js
(function(){
  var app=angular.module('Tester',[]);
  
  app.controller('TestController',function($scope){
    $scope.days=[{name:'Sun'},{name:'Mon'},{name:'Teu'},{name:'Wed'},{name:'Thu'},{name:'Fri'},{name:'Sat'}];
    //if I is use `days=['Sun','Mon'...]` it works
    $scope.values={};
    $scope.add=function(values){
      var sum=0;
      $scope.days.map(function(v){
        v=values[v.name];
        if(v){
          sum+=(v-0)||0;
        }
      });
      return sum;
    }
  });
  
  app.filter('sum',function(){
    return function(obj){
      var total=0;
      for(var v in obj){
        total+=(obj[v]-0)||0;
      }
      return total;
    }
  });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Tester">
  <div ng-controller="TestController as test">
    <input ng-model="values[day.name]" value="{{values[day.name]||0}}" ng-repeat="day in days">
    <div>{{add(values)}}</div>
    <div>{{values | sum}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning angular and thought i had messed up using it instead a simple bug like that.